# 404 page not found in django localhost when try to click on image url

Tags: django, api, heroku, django-rest-framework, media

I created menu objects from Django default admin panel on which one of the fields is an image. I have successfully uploaded the image as well. But in the response api, if I clicked on image url, it says **404 not found**.

The api response is like this.

[image]

Both image_url and image are 404 not found.

[image]

I added image_url just to see if it works, but it didn't work as well.

My model:

```
class Menus(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=CATEGORY,default='main courses')
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
My serializers:

class MenusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')    

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        image_url = obj.image.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)



    class Meta:
        model = Menus
        fields = ['category','image', 'image_url','food_name',
                  'description','price','rating']
```

My settings:

```
# BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

My project urls:py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I tried many things, putting just urlpatterns for media. Also,I commented out the media_root and defined in a new way, changed database name etc. But nothing seems to be working. Is it because I have installed heroku on this project?? But the local should be showing the images.

Comment: Isnt collectstatic command used for static files only and not for media files?? I can see picture files in media folder in my root directory.